# SCons - Add dependency for all objects in a library

Tags: c, build, scons

I have this `SConstruct` file:

```
lib=Library("foo", "foo.c", CPPFLAGS="-include foo.h")
```

Because of `-include`, I need to recompile whenever `foo.h` changes. SCons doesn't automatically figure this out.

I tried adding a dependecy - `Depends(lib, "foo.h")` - but it only causes a useless relink.

How can I make `foo.c` recompile when `foo.h` changes?

Extra credit - what I really need is to recompile not only when `foo.h` changes, but also when headers it includes change. But detecting `foo.h` changes are good enough.

Comment: Wouldn't you then want an explicit dependency of `Depends("foo.o", "foo.h")`? Additionally, my guess is that this is just a toy example for the more general problem of automatically adding `foo.h` as dependency to *all* object files. I simply doubt it's just this one file per library for your actual application, am I right?

Comment: @dirkbaechle, Your suggestion works, but I don't think it's robust (it assumes that `foo.c` compiles into `foo.o`). And yes - it's a highly simplified example, I have many sources.

Comment: BTW, back in the old days when i had to program under Windows, we would experiment with things like "forced includes" and "precompiled headers"...trying to be lazy, or "clever" as some people might call it. ;) Note that these special include header setups may not only break SCons, but other tools like Insure++ by Parasoft don't understand them either. So in the long run you'll stumble into problems again and again, and it might be worth considering to simply do the cumbersome work of adding "foo.h" to each source file...you could write a script for *that* perhaps?

Comment: @dirkbaechle, You're right, but I have some reasons. I'm trying to make some files compile in some strange environment, without modifying them. `-include` is very useful here.

Answer (score 1):

As a first shot this is the best I can come up with:

```
# Construct special environment
env = Environment()
env.Append(CPPFLAGS = ['-include', 'foo.h'])

# Compile objects separately
objs = env.Object(Glob('*.c'))

# Add explicit dependencies
add_deps = ['foo.h']
for o in objs:
    env.Depends(o, add_deps)

# Create final library
env.Library('myfoo', objs)
```

The extension `*.o` isn't mentioned directly anywhere in the build description, and `add_deps` can easily be extended by the headers that get included via "`foo.h`".